# With regards to algorithms what's exactly a free-primitive?

Tags: algorithms

With regards to algorithms does anyone could explain what's exactly a *free-primitive*?

By chance is a *free-primitive* any kinda sorting?

I've read about that from book *Algorithms Illuminated Part 1: The Basics by Tim Roughgarden* page 31.

Comment: A reference to a commercial book is of no use.

Comment: It might help if you gave a quotation from that book with sufficient context that would help us understand in what context this term is being used?  Please don't use "Edit:".  Just revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

No. *Free-primitive* is not any particular algorithm. The author has himself chosen this notion to make the writing interesting.

By calling an algorithm *primitive*, he mean that the algorithm is so basic that many other complex algorithms frequently use it as a subroutine. Moreover, by calling an algorithm a *free-primitive*, he mean that the running time of the algorithm is small so that one can freely use it anytime for pre-processing etc.; it won't impact the overall running time too much. For example, sorting which has near linear running time $O(n \log n)$, is used almost most anytime in many complex algorithms like [range searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching), [graph algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm), [scheduling problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling), etc.